# How to convert Map<Shape, int[]> to Map<Shape, Set<Integer>> in Java 8?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, set

I'm pretty new to Java 8 and I have the following requirement to convert:

```
Map<Shape, int[]> --> Map<Shape, Set<Integer>>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've edited the question in hope that a `Set<Integer>` is what you *really need*, cause you can't have a primitive `Set` of type `Set<int>`.

```
 map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Entry::getKey,
                    x -> Arrays.stream(x.getValue()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet())

    ));
```

On the other hand if you really want unique primitives, then a `distinct` and `toArray` will work, but the type is still going to be `Map<Shape, int[]>`:

```
 map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Entry::getKey,
                    x -> Arrays.stream(x.getValue()).distinct().toArray()

    ));
```

Comment: Maybe add a comment telling that it's not possible to get a `Set<int>` but only a `Set<Integer>`?

Comment: Isn't it possible to box the int[] in the same phase of converting the map?

Comment: Thank you guy, your answered got me to the right solution!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method to transform an `int` array to a `Set<Integer>`:

```
private Set<Integer> convertArrayToSet(int[] array) {
    return stream(array).boxed().collect(toSet());
}
```

You need to skip each value of the map through this method:

```
public Map<Shape, Set<Integer>> convert(Map<Shape, int[]> map) {
    return map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> convertArrayToSet(e.getValue())));
}
```

*I used static imports of `Arrays`, `Collectors` to make the snippets shorter.*